# How to calculate a new field in python using a linear relationship

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am new to python, working with python 2.7.5, After i read a csv file in python using below code:

```
df = csv.DictReader(open("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\file.csv")).
```

I want to calculate a new field(or column), for which the value can be derived using the existing headers of the csv file.The value of new field(call it,n_val) can be derived as

`:n_val = lf[0]*co[0] + lf[1]*co[1] +5`

where "lf" and "co" are my list. "lf" list contains field names as list values something like ['x','y'], and "co" contains the coefficients values of x and y in list as [2.08,9.3].

Since the csv file contains the values of x and y in a form something like below(shown as Input). I want to calculate new_val and print it on the screen(as output)

```
Input:
x  y
02 04
03 05
61 17
12 56
09 23

Output:
x  y  new_val
02 04 46.36
03 05 57.74
61 17 289.98
12 56 550.76
09 23 237.62
```

Any help in this regard is much appreciated and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to use pandas, you can load data into pandas DataFrame with [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) method (see some examples [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Documents\file.csv')
```

And after that you can use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function, with axis=1 (means apply function to each row):

```
>>> df['new_val'] = df.apply(lambda row: sum(row[lf[i]]*co[i] for i in range(len(lf)))+5, axis=1)
>>> df
    x   y  new_val
0   2   4    46.36
1   3   5    57.74
2  61  17   289.98
3  12  56   550.76
4   9  23   237.62
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working,Its throwing a traceback and which says: AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute 'apply', is it because i am reading this as a dictonary?

Comment: @pradeep6kumar sorry, added some code about loading data to pandas DataFrame

Comment: No issues and thanks a ton, Its perfect and working, +1 for this. I just want to know where i can learn more about pandas,if you know some links to read.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort